# I got an error invalid operands of types ‘Matrix<int>*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator*’

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, class-template

I am trying scalar multiplication with class template
This is my operand

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T> :: operator*(T &scalar){
Matrix result(row,cols,0.0);
unsigned i,j;
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        result(i,j) = this->matrix[i][j]* scalar;
    }
}
return result;
}
```

And this is My main

```
Matrix<int> *m1 = new Matrix<int>();
Matrix<int> *m2 = new Matrix<int>(5,5 ,7); //meaning 5x5 all matris value = 7
Matrix<int> *m3 = new Matrix<int>(5,5,'e');//meaning 5x5 unit matrix
Matrix<int> *m4 = new Matrix<int>(3,3,'r');//meaning 3x3 random value matrix
m3=m3*2;
```

So I got error

```
invalid operands of types ‘Matrix<int>*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator*’
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Anyhow, the problem is that you are writing Java or C# code using C++. Please read a good C++ tutorial and pay particularly attention to the use of `new` or, rather, the lack thereof!

Comment: Why do you even use dynamic memory allocation? `Matrix<int> *m3 = new Matrix<int>(5,5,'e');` -> `Matrix<int> m3 = Matrix<int>(5,5,'e');` and your problems will be solved.

Comment: I must use dynamic memory allocation. This is homework and they want it :(